# $ {1\over(1-x)}=\sum^n_{k=0}x^k + {x^{n+1}\over(1-x)}\space (when\space x\neq 1) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ {1\over(1-x)}=\sum^n_{k=0}x^k + {x^{n+1}\over(1-x)}\space (when\space x\neq 1) $$

How does this equation hold true when $x\neq1$? I know for a fact that $${1\over(1-x)}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}x^k$$ holds true only when $|x|<1$. The first equation only seems like a variation of the second equation, but I can't grasp why the range of $x$ has changed.

Comment: When $x\ne1$ both sides of the first equation have finitely many terms and represent finite values. In the second example the RHS can diverge to infinity.

Comment: There is a formula for a finite sum like this, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645248/partial-sums-of-geometric-series. There it shows that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ for all $x\ne 1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman I can't believe I was foolish enough to miss that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that $$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

If we add $\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, we get $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Therefore $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k + \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

The reason that the condition $|x| < 1$ is present for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ is so that the sum converges. Since that condition is not needed for a finite sum to converge, the above equality is satisfied for all $x \not = 1$.